P-Channel MOSFET conducting when it should not be
I am breadboarding a circuit to verify that a particular circuit to switch between USB and battery power works as expected. Specifically the circuit shown at the link below that is intended to use USB power were it present, but battery power if USB power is not. In my implementation I am intending for a 7.4V Li Ion battery pack to be utilized.
I've breadboarded the circuit with a IRF9540N MOSFET and am using two lab power supplies with current monitoring to verify power draws, the "battery" supply set to 7.4V and the "USB" supply set to 5V. The problem I'm encountering is that the "battery" is always powering, even with the "USB" source present. Upon doing some testing, the circuit works as intended until the "battery" supply reaches ~6.6V at which point the "battery" starts conducting and the "USB" draw starts to decline. At about 7.2V the "USB" supply is no longer supplying and it is all "battery" power. Why might this be the case?
Other post: switch between battery and usb power no microcontroller circuit
Circuit:


Isn’t the P-mos misswired? The D and S swapped? Check if body diode is in direction as in schematic.

Validated that diodes are placed in the correct direction. I believe the schematic is correct above, VCC into FET source and GND to FET drain. Any other thoughts?

If you analyze Vgs for the MOSFET in your various scenarios you should be able to see why this is happening.

Your USB voltage (gate voltage) is fixed at 5V so when your battery (source) voltage rises above that, Q4's channel begins to conduct like normal (Vgs < 0). You need some other way of keeping Q4 turned off.

The P-MOSFET you use begins to switch on below 2 V (Vth), so when BAT is over main supply this amount, current will flow from BAT.
You can select a P-MOSFET with Vth(min) > 3 V, but lower than BAT; that way it will be switched off when BAT-MAIN < Vth.
Other solution is to shift the gate voltage with a zener, with a breakdown voltage of about 3 V. See diagram

